# How do I migrate my home screen?

Tags: home-screen, device-migration

My old Moto G 1st generation fell and broke, and I've just bought a new Moto E (2nd generation). It looks like the Motorola Migration app copied all my data. Almost my apps are being reinstalled (I've tried to delete some unused ones before migrating, but are being installed anyway).

The only thing missing is my Home Screen, with my icons organization and widgets. Is there an easy way to do it? Or I must reorganize everything by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there's no way to migrate this between devices unless you're using the Google Now Launcher on the old phone, and the new phone ships with it as its default. It's designed to migrate layout, but the stock launcher that Motorola uses doesn't have this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an automated way.

So I take an screenshot of my old device and manually organize the new following pictures.